# Make a grandchild element have the grandfather element content as background

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div, that has two divs.

One div works as a background and has a background image, and other one works as the content and has a background color of #fff, the one that works as a content has a title and an input.

**I was trying make a border for my input , that shows what is behind the content div.**

Because the proportions of the the background div changes on hover(on pupose), changing the way the border of the input should look.

So i decided to have a div as the border of the input.
But i have been stuck on trying to make the border to show what is behind the content div.

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
#chat_bi{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
top:0;

 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/GProxpt.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 z-index: -1;
 filter: brightness(60%);
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
     transition: 0.5s;
 
}
#outer_div_chat{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 height: calc(100% - 400px);
 padding: 50px;
 
}
.chat{
 padding: 15px;
 z-index: 2;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     background-color: #fff;
}
#outer_div_chat:hover #chat_bi{
    width:  105% !important;
    height:  105% !important;
 filter:  brightness(95%);
}
#start_up_chat_div{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
/*text-input*/
.text_input_div{

 padding:5px;
 background-image:  url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/GProxpt.jpg");
 
}
.text_input{
 outline:none;
 padding:2px 4px;
 border:none;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:625px; overflow:hidden;">
<div id="outer_div_chat">
   <div id="chat_bi"></div>
   <div class="chat">
    <div id="start_up_chat_div" >
     <span style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Random text</span>
     <div class="text_input_div">
      <input type="text" class="text_input">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I kind of guess that one solution is applying, the same background to the border of the input div, in the same position, and size, but i was wondering if there is another way around, a more proper way around.

Comment: Sorry, you have to be more specific what exactly you need. What's your goal? What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: Regarding the edited question, what content is that arrow pointing to? It might be worth taking a look at the "*[ask]*" guidelines to help us to help you.

Comment: so, you want the border of the box to be the background-image, to make it seem like transparent ... phuuu, no easy task, my friend... good luck with that!

Comment: @ad_on_is You are right, that is my intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

CSS

```
.bigcrazydivwithbackground {
background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/28477/pexels-photo-28477.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
}

.crazytitle {
background: white;
padding: 10px;
}

.crazyinner {
border: 20px solid white;
}

.crazyinputwrapper {
margin: 20px;
}

input {
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: white;
line-height: 20px;
border: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bigcrazydivwithbackground">
<div class="crazybox">
<div class="crazytitle">
    Title
</div>

<div class="crazyinner">
    <div class="crazyinputwrapper">
    <input type="text" />
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLphc3nu/

Comment: Nice approach.Kind of a hack.

Comment: Using borders as padding, is it correct way of programming css?Is there some kind of depreciation to it?Anyway thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not a hack, it's the easiest and cleanest way to do - and it's bulletproof ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of position: absolute and position: relative, make them both position:absolute so the z-index's will work. Sometimes using a negative z-index might also be the problem.

Start at 0 and go up from there, rather than using -1. For instance, set the div containing your inputs and labels to a z-index of 100, and give the image you want to place behind it a z-index of 50.